# Trying to convert a POSIX based system to Windows

Tags: c++, multithreading, networking, posix, winsock

I'm currently trying to convert a multithreaded LAN tic tac toe game so it compiles / works on my Windows system. I'm quite new to networking but I've managed to translate a lot of the system calls to Socket API calls however I am having trouble understanding how to convert the 'pthread' functions. Most of the questions I see online are asking how to compile it, but I want to change it instead of adding new libraries etc.

Can someone please shed some light on what exactly pthread does and how I can change it to compile in the native windows environment.
Thanks!

**Main Function**

```
pthread_mutex_t games_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int main() {

    //Initialise Winsock
    WSAData data;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &data);

    if (wsResult != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Can't start Winsock, Err #" << wsResult << endl;
    }

    // Signals used to kill the server gracefully
    if (signal(SIGINT, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        perror("Can't catch SIGINT");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (signal(SIGTERM, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        perror("Can't catch SIGTERM");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Initialize the server and get the server's socket
    server_sock = init_server();

    int new_socket = 0;

    // Infinitely accept clients and spawning threads
    while (true)
    {
        // Wait for a client, and then accept
        if ((new_socket = accept(server_sock, NULL, NULL)) < 0)
        {
            perror("Failed to accept client");
            closesocket(server_sock);
            exit(1);
        }

        cout << "New client connected" << endl;

        // Spawn thread to handle the client
        pthread_t threadid;
        pthread_create(&threadid, NULL, handle_client, (void*)&new_socket);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Client Handle Function**

```
{
    int client_sock = *(int*)arg;
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    bool client_connected = true;
    char temp = '\0';
    int row = 0, col = 0;
    int i = 0;

    // Create the player
    Player player(client_sock);

    // Always handle the client
    while (client_connected)
    {
        // Process commands or pass game data
        if (player.GetMode() == COMMAND)
        {
            // Read a line of text or until the buffer is full
            for (i = 0; (i < (BUF_SIZE - 1)) && temp != '\n' && client_connected; ++i)
            {
                // Receive a single character and make sure the client is still connected
                if (recv(client_sock, &temp, 1, 0) == 0)
                    client_connected = false;
                else
                    buffer[i] = temp;
            }

            // Reset temp so we don't get an infinite loop
            temp = '\0';
            buffer[i] = '\0';
            buffer[i - 1] = '\0';
            cout << "Received command \"" << buffer << "\" from " << player.GetName() << endl;
            buffer[i - 1] = '\n';

            // If there's an invalid command, tell the client
            if (!ProcessCommand(buffer, player, client_connected))
                SendStatus(player.GetSocket(), INVALID_CMD);
        }
        else if (player.GetMode() == INGAME)
        {
            // Get the game the player is a part of
            pthread_mutex_lock(&games_lock);
            auto game = find_if(game_list.begin(), game_list.end(),
                [player](TTTGame* game) { return game->HasPlayer(player); });
            auto end = game_list.end();
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&games_lock);

            // Something horrible has gone wrong
            if (game == end)
                cout << "Somehow Player " << player.GetName() << " isn't a part of a game but is INGAME" << endl;
            else
            {
                StatusCode status;
                client_connected = ReceiveStatus(player.GetSocket(), &status);

                // If the player is still connected, then perform the move
                if (client_connected)
                {
                    switch (status)
                    {
                    case MOVE:
                        // Pass the row and column right along
                        ReceiveInt(player.GetSocket(), &row);
                        ReceiveInt(player.GetSocket(), &col);
                        cout << "Received moved from " << player.GetName()
                            << ": row=" << row << ", col=" << col << endl;

                        SendStatus((*game)->GetOtherPlayer(player).GetSocket(), MOVE);
                        SendInt((*game)->GetOtherPlayer(player).GetSocket(), row);
                        client_connected = SendInt((*game)->GetOtherPlayer(player).GetSocket(), col);
                        cout << "Sent move to " << (*game)->GetOtherPlayer(player).GetName() << endl;

                        break;
                    case WIN:
                        cout << player.GetName() << " won a game against " << (*game)->GetOtherPlayer(player).GetName() << endl;
                        client_connected = false;
                        break;
                    case DRAW:
                        cout << player.GetName() << " tied against " << (*game)->GetOtherPlayer(player).GetName() << endl;
                        client_connected = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        client_connected = SendStatus(player.GetSocket(), INVALID_CMD);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // The client disconnected on us D:
    cout << "Player \"" << player.GetName() << "\" has disconnected" << endl;
    DisconnectPlayer(player);
    closesocket(client_sock);
    WSACleanup();

    return (void*)0;
}
```

These are just some examples of the code. I am happy to post more if needed.

Comment: Suggestion without actually having looked at the code (sorry): have a look at c++'s std::thread, it is based on pthread and it should be supported on all platforms and it should work fine for a simple, non-time-based game.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'm trying std::mutex, will let you know how it goes.